# Power BI: Filter a table on the one side of a many to one join, by using a slicer from the many side table

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I have an application that retrieves both single and multi-select values for various fields for a specific identifier.

The structure of one of tables looks like that in 'Table1' below, while field4 and field5 retrieve all of the values in the multiselect for each identifier.

We also have a table that contains a breakdown of these multiselects for each identifier and for each field (Table2). The tables are joined on identifier.

The users would like to be able filter the data in table 1, by using a slicer based upon the value field in Table2. Unfortunately as the cardinality of the two tables are 1 (Table1) to Many (Table2), the slicer does not work unless I use bi-directional filtering.

Due to potential ambiguous results and negative performance, I obviously do not want to use this method unless absolutely necessary. Table 1 would likely consist of 200k records, with around 150 columns, and Table 2 would consist of 500k records.

Is there another solution other than bi-directional filter?

[image]

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text. Please mark your old questions as solved.

Comment: Thanks David. I have done. Extremely 'sample' data as follows:

identifier field1 field2 field3 field4 field5
ID1 a b c shark, tiger x, y
ID2 d e f tiger, eagle, shark y, z
ID3 g h i eagle x, z
     
     
identifier attribute value  Table2 
ID1 field4 shark   
ID1 field4 tiger   
ID1 field5 x   
ID1 field5 y   
ID2 field4 tiger   
ID2 field4 eagle   
ID2 field4 shark   
ID2 field5 y   
ID2 field5 z   
ID3 field4 eagle   
ID3 field5 x   
ID3 field5 z

Comment: Do you wants to check Value from Table2 is available in column "Field4" and "Field5" or not?

Comment: Hi mkRabbani. No, the users would like to slicer table 1 to check whether 'shark' for example is present, by selecting attribute = 'field4' and value = 'shark'. In this instance the records for ID1 & ID2 would be returned.

Comment: The bi-directional filter is really your best move here. 200k records is not a crazy amount, it should be able to handle fine unless you have some more complex measures that would be dependent on the relationship. I've used bi-directional filters successfully with 10m+ records.